# Using double map function in Python API of GEE to get an annual time series by reducing a collection to monthly and then anuual

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have tried to compute an annual time series using python API. I have used two map function to iterate over years and month to get a time by reducing a collection of L8 image to a monthly image collection by years and then to annual series.
I used a `partial` function from `functools` to accomplish the same. But, it shows a value error:`ValueError: Function has keyword-only parameters or annotations, use inspect.signature() API which can support them`

```py
from functools import partial 

def daily2monthly2annual(year, ndvi_collection):
    months = ee.List.sequence(1,12)
    ndvi_coll_ann = ndvi_collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, field = 'year'))
    
    img_coll= ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
        months.map(lambda month:
                  ndvi_coll_ann \
                  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, field = 'month')) \
                  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()))
        
    )
    img_coll = img_coll \
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()) \
        .rename('ndvi') \
        .addBands(ee.Image().constant(year).float().rename('year')) 
        .set('year',year)
    return img_coll

def int_yearly_ndvi(ndvi_coll, start, end):
    """Function to integrate observed NDVI datasets at the annual level"""
    
    years = ee.List.sequence(start, end)
## need to change the scope of this varibale to global
    img_coll = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
        years.map(partial(daily2monthly2annual, ndvi_collection=ndvi_coll)
    )
   
    return img_coll
```

Then I tried without the `partial` function.

```py
def int_yearly_ndvi(ndvi_coll, start, end):
    """Function to integrate observed NDVI datasets at the annual level"""
    def daily_to_monthly_to_annual(year):
        months = ee.List.sequence(1,12)
        ndvi_collection = ndvi_coll
        ndvi_coll_ann = ndvi_collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, field = 'year'))
    
        img_coll= ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
        months.map(lambda month:
                  ndvi_coll_ann \
                  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, field = 'month')) \
                  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()))
             )
        img_coll_ndvi = img_coll \
            .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()) \
            .float() \
            .rename('ndvi') \
            .addBands(ee.Image().constant(year).float().rename('year')) \
            .set('year',year)
        return img_coll_ndvi
    years = ee.List.sequence(start, end)
    img_coll = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
        years.map(daily_to_monthly_to_annual)
    )
   
    return img_coll
```

The above function is working perfectly with this aoi:`'users/amitghosh/ER/IN/KillaiRF'` but throwing an error with this aoi: `'users/himal781/Indonesia_AOI'`

Error massage : `Collection.toList: Error in map (ID=1): image.select: Pattern 'ndvi' did not match any bands`

I think the issue is related to the missing scenes in some months. Then how to get the month number dynamically?

Or is there a better approach do the same?

Here are supporting function/code that you need to reproduce the same.

```py
def rename_band(img):
    img = img.select(['B4', 'B5', 'pixel_qa'],['Red', 'NIR', 'pixel_qa'])
    return img

def CalcNDVI(img):
    """compute the ndvi on renamed bands"""
    
    red = img.select('Red')
    nir = img.select('NIR')
    
    ndvi = nir.subtract(red) \
        .divide(nir.add(red)) \
        .multiply(10000) \
        .rename('ndvi') \
        .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'))
    
    return ndvi

######################################################
i_img_coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('users/amitghosh/ER/IN/KillaiRF')
#aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('users/himal781/Indonesia_AOI')
i_img_coll = i_img_coll.filterDate(f'{2016}-01-01', f'{2020}-12-31').filterBounds(aoi)
i_img_coll = i_img_coll.map(rename_band)
ndvi_img = i_img_coll.map(CalcNDVI)
int_yearly_ndvi =int_yearly_ndvi(ndvi_img, 2016,2020)
```

Comment: In some months there is no scene available  'users/himal781/Indonesia_AOI' in this region. That is the main issue I presume. Then, how to overcome this situation?

Comment: Please do not comment on your own Question. This should be an [Edit] instead.

Comment: @Vince, Done! as per your suggestion